# Insert strongly typed list into Sql table

Tags: t-sql, list, strongly-typed-dataset

I am trying to find a different way to insert a strongly typed List into a SQL table. The only way that crossed my mind is to serialize List as XML and pass it as a param of type XML to SQL.

Process is fairly simple, and it works fine, but I am trying to see it there is a better alternative to this solution?

Comment: User-Defined-Type might be what you are looking for http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to insert a list into a database table? I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you could certainly represent each node in your list as a row in a database table. The table would have columns for each field in your class and an extra column called "ListRank" storing a node's position in the list. If you created a linq-to-sql connection, then you could easily get the list from the DB with a simple query.

```
Dim myDB as Datacontext = new DataContext()
Dim students as List(Of Student) = (From s as student in myDB.students select s order by s.listRank ascending).toList
'//students now holds (Bob, A), (Sue, B)
```

The table would look something like:

```
Name      Grade    ListRank
======== ========  =========
  Bob       A        1
  Sue       B        2
```

**Note**You would have to create a uniqueness constraint on ListRank in the DB so that you could be sure that no two students had the same list rank/position in the list.